# node style is only taking partial effect in a matrix of nodes

Tags: nodes, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

This is probably the first of two closely related questions.

I have defined a style:

```
  my node style/.style={%%
    minimum width=\dimexpr0.60in+12pt\relax,
    minimum height=\dimexpr0.30cm+12pt\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    draw},
```

I would like not to have to declare the node style within each cell of my table; rather, I would prefer to do this using the keys such as:

```
row 3 column 2/.style={my node style}
```

However, when I do this, everything about `my node style` takes effect except for `draw` (there is no such problem when this node style is declared within each cell where I want it to apply).

Here's a MWE illustrating this problem:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{%%
  >=Stealth,
  my node style/.style={%%
    minimum width=\dimexpr0.60in+12pt\relax,
    minimum height=\dimexpr0.30cm+12pt\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    draw},
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \matrix (TBL) [%%
                 matrix of nodes,
                 nodes={%%
                   align=center,
                   inner sep=0pt,
                   anchor=center},
                 column 2/.style={column sep=-0.4pt},
                 column 3/.style={column sep=-0.4pt},
                 column 4/.style={column sep=-0.4pt},
                 column 5/.style={column sep=-0.4pt},
                 row 3 column 2/.style={my node style},
                 row 3 column 3/.style={my node style},
                 row 3 column 4/.style={my node style},
                 row 3 column 5/.style={my node style},
                 row 3 column 6/.style={my node style},
                ]
  {
                        & {$(-\infty,-2)$}               & {$(-2,-1)$}                     & {$(-1,1)$}                    & {$(1,2)$}                       & {$(2,\infty)$}                 \\[2pt]
   {$\abs{x^{2}-1}=\,$} & |[my node style]| {$x^{2}-1 $} & |[my node style]| {$x^{2}-1$}   & |[my node style]| {$1-x^{2}$} & |[my node style]| {$x^{2}-1$}   & |[my node style]| {$x^{2}-1$}  \\[-0.4pt]
   {$\abs{x^{2}-4}=\,$} &                   {$x^{2}-4 $} &                   {$4-x^{2}$}   &                   {$4-x^{2}$} &                   {$4-x^{2}$}   &                   {$x^{2}-4$}  \\[2pt]
   {$g(x) =$}           & |[my node style]| {$ 3 $ }     & |[my node style]| {$ 2x^{2}-5$} & |[my node style]| {$ -3 $}    & |[my node style]| { $2x^{2}-5$} & |[my node style]| {$ 3 $}      \\
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `my node style` needs to go in the `nodes={}` key. A cell has no `draw` attribute, but the node inside the cell has. See my other answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my node style` needs to go in the `nodes={}` key. A cell has no `draw` attribute, but the node inside the cell has. Thus, it needs to be passed to the node to be drawn in the cell. The simplest mechanism for that is the `nodes` key.

So the only modification required is

```
row 3 column <col no>/.style={nodes={my node style}},
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add the option `nodes=draw` to the `my node style`. Then the node inside a cell will also be drawn.

```
 my node style/.style={%%
    minimum width=\dimexpr0.60in+12pt\relax,
    minimum height=\dimexpr0.30cm+12pt\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    draw,
    nodes=draw}
```

[image]